# Formatting Dates in LINQ query when using GroupBy

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have the following linq query where I am grouping students based on their birthday: month/year. If two students were born in the same month/year then they would get grouped together. I would like to be able to modify this query so that it can return the dates formatted as "Sep/1997, May/2005" etc. Any idea if this is doable with passing a new object to `GroupBy()` or is a new approach needed?

```
void Main()
{
    var getStudents = new List<Student>
    {
        new Student{Id = 1, Name = "Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1997, 09, 23)},
        new Student{Id = 2, Name = "John", Birthday = new DateTime(1997, 09, 23)},
        new Student{Id = 3, Name = "Jim", Birthday = new DateTime(1998, 09, 25)},
        new Student{Id = 4, Name = "Jack", Birthday = new DateTime(2000, 11, 3)},
        new Student{Id = 5, Name = "Willy", Birthday = new DateTime(2005, 05, 10)},
        new Student{Id = 6, Name = "Luke", Birthday = new DateTime(2005, 05, 11)},
        new Student{Id = 7, Name = "Lilly", Birthday = new DateTime(2005, 05, 21)}
    };
    
    var groupDate = getStudents.OrderBy(x => x.Birthday).GroupBy(x => new { x.Birthday.Month, x.Birthday.Year })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new
    {
        names = x.Select(n => n.Name).ToList(),
        awardDate = string.Format("{0}/{1}", x.Key.Month, x.Key.Year),
    });
    Console.WriteLine(groupDate);
    
}

class Student
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public DateTime Birthday;
}
```

Comment: In what way is your current query not doing what you expect? Are you just struggling to [format dates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) the way you want in the output? Or are you saying you want LINQ to Entities to do the translation at the database layer? Why is that? Why don't you want to pass "a new object to GroupBy()"?

Comment: To format the dates at the database layer, I like the object being passed to the GroupBy() currently. When I get the dates I would like them to be in the format as above

Comment: Have you tried `getStudents.OrderBy(x => x.Birthday).GroupBy(x => x.Birthday.ToString("MMM/yy"))` - that will most likely evaluate the group by locally. ?

Comment: Can you try group them with `year` and `dayOfYear` like this `.GroupBy(x => new { x.Birthday.DayOfYear, x.Birthday.Year })`. This way you can group them year of day and year.

Comment: Why do you want the date formatting to be done at the database layer? What benefit do you expect to get from that? And is it enough of a benefit that you're willing to have your code get ugly and complicated in order to make it work?

Comment: var groupDate = getStudents.OrderBy(x => x.Birthday).GroupBy(x => new { x.Birthday.Month, x.Birthday.Year })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new
    {
        names = x.Select(n => n.Name).ToList(),
        awardDate = x.Select(s => s.Birthday.ToString("MMM/yyyy")).FirstOrDefault(),
    });

Comment: @user3026017 answer also works as well

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't give me the ability to raise a vote for those answers or give them the credit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var groupDatee = getStudents.OrderBy(x => x.Birthday).GroupBy(x => x.Birthday.ToString("MMM,yyyy"))
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new
    {
        names = x.Select(n => n.Name).ToList(),
        awardDate = x.Key,
    });
```